# Ошибка Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Недавно я решил изучить фреймворк Kivy Python3. Установил как показанно в [документации](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html). Написал небольшой код для проверки и получил ошибку. Можете пожалуйста сказать как это исправить. ОП Ubuntu Gnome 3. Версия Python - 3.5. Версия Kivy - 1.9.1

Вот код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return  Button(
            text = "Нажми на меня"
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Вот ошибка:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/dima/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-03-20_3.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.3 (default, Nov 23 2017, 11:34:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - TypeError: expected bytes, str found
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 237, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 94, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1936)

x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/utils.py", line 513, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/metrics.py", line 175, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 126, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: пример кода работает как есть. Похоже у вас установка kivy неудачно прошла. Попробуйте: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy;` `sudo apt-get update;` `sudo apt-get install python3-kivy` Если не сработает, задайте отдельный вопрос о том как установить kivy на вашу платформу.

Answer (score 0):

Не builder , а build!

```
class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Поменял builder(self) на build(self) ошибка осталась.

Comment: Как запускаешь скрипт?

Comment: В терминале открываю папку с файлом python3 MyApp.py

Comment: Попробуйте запустить не из консоли, путем двойного клика по файлу. Хотя, согласен, видимо, установка прошла не совсем корректно.

Comment: Я переустановил киви и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы устанавливали Kivy с помощью virtualenv, то не забывайте запускать сначала виртуальное окружение.
У меня такое было, что я открыл второе окно терминала и не мог никак запустить программу. Оказалось, что я просто забыл войти в виртуальное окружение